# Apptentive Ratings Prompt

Tags: android, apptentive

I am trying to integrate Apptentive in my project. I have followed all the guideline in the documentation (i.e. created event, added apptentive_api_key in manifest file). Now when is write `boolean shown = Apptentive.engage(NewDashboard.this, "Mock_Test_Clicked");` it returns false. Also the Ratings Prompt screen is not shown.

```
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart(); 
  Apptentive.onStart(this); 
} 

public void onStop() {
  super.onStop(); 
  Apptentive.onStop(this);
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<meta-data android:name="apptentive_api_key"
           android:value="APPTENTIVE_API_KEY"‌/>
<activity android:name="com.apptentive.android.sdk.ViewActivity"
          android:theme="@style/Apptentive.Theme.Transparent"/>
```

Comment: share some code or link anything so that we may check

Comment: https://be.apptentive.com/apps/54eaeba78aa3f25585000022/ratings_prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your app hasn't been able to connect to the Apptentive server, so it hasn't been able to download a list of interactions. I suggest you email support@apptentive.com.

Comment: I have mailed my concern to support@apptentive.com, and waiting for their response. By the way Thanks @sky Kelsey